# Can I make a distinction between a "scraper" and a casual browser?

Tags: logging, web-scraping, server, hosting

**Will there be a difference in data from**

- Normal page view
- Scraper tool
- Manual save of an image on the page (*right-click save*)

---

Background: a competitor decided to steal pixel for pixel the entirety of my one page website. I was tipped off to this by seeing 25,000+ clicks in my google analytics going to pages I’ve never created.

I’m familiar with tools like website ripper copier/httools/etc and also of course know they can just right click and save all images and copy paste the code but I’m hoping these people were careless and left tracks in the log.

I use bluehost vps and have a cpanel. It’s a basic html css website.

Perhaps if it’s from a specific copier tool I can see that?
Or maybe I can see a difference between images being loaded on page view and images being downloaded by right clicking?

Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 0):

A [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string is normally sent by by a well behaved browser, and you might notice also Google (or someone pretending to be them) will send something like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.96 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

*Malicious software can always imitate some legitimate browser by simply sending the same string as e.g. Firefox.*

All browsers that I know of send the same Useragent regardless of whether you right-click and ‘save-as’ on a link—something like an image would be present in the browser's cache already and I imagine would not even trigger a second request after the page loads.

You may find yourself lucky and find someone using a tool with a unique user-agent that would make it distinct from the other traffic—failing this I'd think if the “thief” was using one computer and one internet connection you can likely see tons of connections from a single IP address in your logfiles… rapid fire requests from one IP (or group of IPs in the same area?, seek a GeoIP Database to correlate) all within a narrow timeframe.